# Why can't I "git clone" from my server with a key that works from my local machine?

Tags: git

This is the content of /home/ubuntu/.ssh

```
drwx------ 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 2011-09-28 02:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 2011-09-28 02:08 ..
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  396 2011-09-27 20:53 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  115 2011-09-27 21:10 config
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1670 2011-09-27 21:10 id_rsa
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  397 2011-09-27 21:10 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  407 2011-09-28 02:07 known_hosts
```

id_rsa.pub is already a key added to my github account because if I try to add it, it tells me it already exists.  It's also the key that allows me to git clone from my local machine.  But when I try to git clone something from the server:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:redCashion/ruby-mysql.git
Cloning into ruby-mysql...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 1):

For diagnostic, try `ssh -T git@github.com`, it should give something like:

```
Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

If that fails, you do not have your keys setup right or it is using some other keys. Try:

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
```

to see what private key it is trying. Make sure it is at `/home/ubuntu/.ssh` like you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ssh'ing directly to github, and it will give you some diagnostic info. On top of that, use `ssh -vvv ...` to get very verbose output about what's happening. You may find that it's not using the key you think it is. If that's the case, check the contents of ~/.ssh/config.